# Piping mssql results to Express response

Tags: sql-server, node.js, express

I'm using [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#streaming) in NodeJS to fetch a large number of rows.

I'd like to pipe the results to a HTTP response in Express, but I can't see how to achieve this.

**db.js**

```
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = {
  user: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  server: 'host',
  database: 'db',
};
```

**index.js**

I am able to stream results to the command line:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
    const request = new sql.Request(pool);
    request.stream = true;
    request.query(`SELECT col1, col2 FROM mytable`);

    request.on('row', row => {
      console.log(row);
    });

  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

However, using request.pipe() results in an error:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {

    const request = new sql.Request(pool);
    request.pipe(res);
    request.query(`SELECT col1, col2 FROM mytable`);

    request.on('finish', () => {
      res.end();
    });

  });
});
```

> _http_outgoing.js:647
>       throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'first argument',
>       ^
>
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of
>   type string or Buffer
>       at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:647:11)
>       at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:622:10)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:180:13

Comment: You are using two requests, one, to sql and the other is, the, presumably, http req object. You are able to stream results to the console because, the request object checks on the 'row' event whereas, you are expecting the 'finish' event on the same object rather than the 'req' object.

Comment: Correction to my above comment: you are calling the 'pipe' method on the same object rather than the 'req' object

Answer (score 0):

edit: if streaming is your concern, why dont you store it in an object

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
    const request = new sql.Request(pool);
    request.stream = true;
    request.query(`SELECT col1, col2 FROM mytable`);
    var output = [];
    request.on('row', row => {
      console.log(row);
      output.push(row)
    });

     request.on('finish', () => {
       res.send(output);
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: This would work, however the point of streaming would be to use a buffer and avoid storing the entire data set in memory. This is why I want to pipe to the response.

Comment: how is that different from storing in an object. the memory still gets used.

Comment: It gets used, but not all at once - A buffer would have a fixed size for streaming larger datasets.

Answer (score -1):

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
    const request = new sql.Request(pool);
    request.stream = true;
    request.query('select * from tableName');
    request.on("row", async (row) => {
        if (
            !res.write(JSON.stringify(row), (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("Failed to send data");                   
                }
            })
        ) {
            request.pause();
            await new Promise((resolve) => res.once("drain", resolve));
            request.resume();
        }
    });
    request.on("error", (err) => {
        res.status(500).send({ message: err });
        res.end();
    });
    request.on("done", (result) => {
        res.end();
        console.log("Data sending complete");
    });
});
});
```